# angularjs ng-table TypeError: Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm new to web development and I struggle using ng-table with angularjs.
My controller is the following:

```
var diary = angular.module('diary', ['ngTable'])
.controller('mainController',['$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams',
        function($scope,$http, NgTableParams){
            $scope.formData = {};
            $scope.courses = [];
            $scope.data = [];

            $scope.getCourses = function(){
                $http.get('/api/courses')
                    .success(function(data) {

                        $scope.courses = data;
                        console.log("data in getCourses " + data);

                    })
                    .error(function(data) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });
            }

            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 150
            }, {
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    console.log('params '+ params)
                    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
                    $scope.getCourses();

                        $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.courses, params.orderBy()) : $scope.courses;
                        $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
                        $scope.data = $scope.data.slice(0, 20);
                        $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                }
            });
        }
        ]
    );
```

The view is this one:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>

<!-- ASSIGN OUR ANGULAR MODULE -->
<html ng-app="diary">
<head>
    <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

    <title>Mountain Diary</title>

    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!-- load bootstrap -->
    <style>
        html                    { overflow-y:scroll; }
        body                    { padding-top:50px; }
        #course-list              { margin-bottom:30px; }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.css">
    <script src="core.js"></script>

</head>
<!-- SET THE CONTROLLER AND GET ALL TODOS -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="container">
    <!-- HEADER AND TODO COUNT -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Mountain Diary - courses: <span class="label label-info">{{ courses.length }}</span></h1>
    </div>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table-striped" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="course in data">
            <td data-title="'id'" sortable="'id'">{{course.id}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'date'" sortable="'date'">{{course.date | date}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'courseType'" sortable="'course.courseType'" filter="{'course.courseType': 'text'}">{{course.courseType | uppercase }} </td>
            <td  data-title="'place'">{{course.place}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'partners'">{{course.partners}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'description'">{{course.description}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'descriptionDetail'">{{course.descriptionDetail}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'descriptionUrl'">{{course.descriptionUrl}}</td>
            <td  data-title="'photoUrl'">{{course.photoUrl}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the index.html I get the error: Cannot read property 'sorting' of undefined.

This means that when the getData function is called the params are empty.

In my opinion when getData function is called the $scope.getCourses success function is not terminated yet (asynchronous), so data are not ready.

But how can I do to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change `$scope.getCourses` to:

```
$scope.getCourses = function(){
    // This function return the `$thhp` promise that resolves with the data returned from the server
    return $http.get('/api/courses').then(
        function(response) {
            // You can also manipulate the data before resolving it here
            return response.data;
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }
    );
}
```

Teen, inside `getData: function ($defer, params) {` call the above function like this:

```
$scope.getCourses().then(
    function(data) {
        var courses = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
         courses = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(courses, params.filter()) : courses;
        courses = courses.slice(0, 20);
        $defer.resolve(courses);
    }
)
```

FYI:

Read this [Deprecation Notice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If [$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#useLegacyPromiseExtensions) is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.

This is why I changed the `$http` inside the `$scope.getCourses` function to `then` instead of using the `success` and `error` callbacks.

Comment: thank you, I did the updates suggested but unfortunately I still get the same error, params is still undefined

Comment: First of all, the [doc](http://ng-table.com/#/) say that you should repeat the data like this `<tr ng-repeat="course in $data">`. And what do you see when you `console.log(params)` inside the `getData` function?

Comment: @user1820620 I added some changes, can you try them please? (And don't forget to change the view to `<tr ng-repeat="course in $data">`

Comment: I did all the changes but still params is undefined in the getData function

Answer (score 0):

Since NgTable version 1.0.0, the formatting of getData has changed. Your getData function should look like so:

```
                getData: function (params) {
                    console.log('params '+ params)
                    // when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
                    $scope.getCourses();

                        $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.courses, params.orderBy()) : $scope.courses;
                        $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
                        $scope.data = $scope.data.slice(0, 20);
                        return $scope.data;
                }
```